# Logical Reads in In-memory optimized tables

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know how to get the number of *pages* in memory we accessed by a query, running on an In-memory optimized table?

Using *sys.dm_exec_query_stats* always returns zero logical reads for any query running on an in-memory table.

```
SELECT * , total_logical_reads
FROM (SELECT QS.*,  SUBSTRING(ST.text, (QS.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,  
((CASE statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(ST.text)  
    ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END - QS.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text  
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS QS  
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) as ST) as query_stats  

total_logical_read = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`In-memory` objects do not use `in-memory` data pages. Data rows have `pointers` to the next row in the row chain.

Here is BOL article that explains it: [Indexes on Memory-Optimized Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/indexes-for-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2017)

> All memory-optimized tables must have at least one index, because it
>   is the indexes that connect the rows together. On a memory-optimized
>   table, every index is also memory-optimized. There are several ways in
>   which an index on a memory-optimized index differs from a traditional
>   index on a disk-base table:
>
> **Data rows are not stored on pages**, so there is no collection of pages
>   or extents, no partitions or allocation units that can be referenced
>   to get all the pages for a table. There is the concept of index pages
>   for one of the available types of indexes, but they are stored
>   differently than indexes for disk-based tables. They do not accrue the
>   traditional type of fragmentation within a page, so they have no
>   fillfactor. Changes made to indexes on memory-optimized tables during
>   data manipulation are never written to disk. Only the data rows, and
>   changes to the data, are written to the transaction log.
>   Memory-optimized indexes are rebuilt when the database is brought back
>   online.